# Temporarily making a cell selectable

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have some cells in a table view that ordinarily aren't selectable.  The user has to use the detail disclosure accessory to push a new controller with the details of the item.

However, on returning to the table view, I would like to highlight the row so that it is clear where s/he came from.  To achieve this, I temporarily set the selectionStyle to blue, select/deselect the row, and then set the selectionStyle back to none.

However, because the cell returns to selectionStyleNone immediately, the end result is a gray select/deselect instead of the blue one.

1) How can I delay this setting of the selectionStyle until the deselect is completed?
2) My cell will temporarily selectable for the fast fingered in the meantime - how might I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple NSTimer to set the selection style to none after a set time frame like so...

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
             target:self
             selector:@selector(methodToSetSelectionStyleToNone:)
             userInfo:nil
             repeats:NO];
```

...or you can use a custom animation to fade it out gracefully

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay: 0.0f
    animations:^{
        // set your selectionStyleNone here
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    completion:^{

    }
];
```

Comment: Bit of hack (which is admittedly what I asked for), but does the job well.

Answer (score 0):

Save your Index Path and use following code whenever you want( viewWillAppear or on another method)

// Pass Saved `NSIndexPath` in below code. By this way even user return from detail view that after he can know that which row was selected by him/her..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[tableView1 selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0]; // you can use this line according your requirements.
}
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: @Ben Packard : Let me know if you find any difficulty in this..Added +1 for good question..

Comment: This is how I am already highlighting the cell.  But my problem is that the cell has a selection style of none.